# запятая: Специалист отдела продаж(,) Иванов И.И. _____________(подпись)

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста!
Ставим запятую или нет?

Специалист отдела продаж,
Иванов И.И.  _____________(подпись)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не ставим. Это же не уточнение.